# Adding additional libraries to Jenkins Workflow classpath

Tags: jenkins-workflow

How can we add libraries to our workflow classpath? e.g. I want to execute some java code in my workflow that requires a third party lib? In my particular case, would like to use AWS Java SDK to execute various AWS tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Workflow is not really meant to call code from external library. There's a detailed explanation of why in [JENKINS-26192](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26192) issue.

Comment: Thanks for that pointer and Jesse's explanation. So, in my specific case that prompted the question, say we want to write a reusable function (I'll call it a plugin) for deploying to AWS CodeDeploy. Is the recommended solution to create a Step for this? Basically, we lose a lot of Jenkins plugins when going to workflow - in order to recreate some of these (JIRA, XL Deploy, etc.) in a workflow-friendly consumable package, do you typically recommend writing a step (https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/tree/master/step-api)?

Answer (score 2):

There is likely an AWS plugin that you can install into Jenkins, and its stuff can used from workflow script. Failing that, you could use: https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/cps-global-lib/README.md to create some functions that call the Java SDK from groovy code that you re-use.

Another option is to use plain sh steps and use the aws CLI (this is often easiest for common actions as those commands are fairly simple and well documented.

Comment: Re: AWS plugin in Jenkins - are you saying if I install a given AWS plugin that it likely includes the Java SDK and that automatically makes its libs available on classpaths of Jenkins scripts (i.e. workflow)?
On that note - is there a lib dir on Jenkins master I could put jars in for this purpose?
Re: cps-global-lib - don't I have same problem, that these scripts won't execute without the appropriate classpath as well? Or is there a way to specify classpath for cps-global-lib?
Re: AWS CLI - that is what I'm doing today, but as our usage grows would be much more convenient to have Java API.

Comment: Yes, you basically have the full classpath available. But there are some limitations: 1. if are using the sandbox then most of the operations will be blocked, and 2. You can not store something non-serializable in a variable (unless you use @NonCps, which has other limitations).

Comment: @amuniz want to make your reply an answer? (and is there a better way to get it in the classpath)

Comment: @MichaelNeale not really. Because it's not what Workflow is designed for. The way to have a feature exposed in Workflow is by adapting the target plugin (or writing a new plugin/step if nothing exists already).